# Please help me understand this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I am trying to understand the sentence below.

"This solution activates both end-to-end cloud services like supply chain visibility or edge services for securely connecting factory devices or deploying core production and supply chain execution capabilities for mission critical factories and warehouse locations."

I believe it says "This solution activates both A and B," but I don't quite understand which part is A, and where the rest is B.

Am I right to understand that A is "end-to-end cloud services," which include

1. supply chain visibility
2. edge services for securely connecting factory devices
3. deploying core production

and B is "supply chain execution capabilities for mission critical factories and warehouse locations"???

Answer (score 1):

This is a horrible sentence, and you probably need domain knowledge to properly parse it. My initial guess would be to split it on 'and' (the first one, the second one combines just 'mission critical factories' and 'warehouse locations'):

> This solution activates both
>
> 1. end-to-end cloud services like
>    a) supply chain visibility
>    or
>    b) edge services for securely connecting factory devices or deploying core production
>    and
> 2. supply chain execution capabilities for
>    a) mission critical factories
>    and
>    b) warehouse locations.

But 'or deploying core production' could very well be 1c)...

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I want to see!  I am still wondering whether "deploying core production" could be 1b or 1c, but 1b makes more sense.